# c# compiler error CS1526: A new expression requires (), [], or {} after type

Tags: c#, constructor, compiler-errors

I am following a tutorial to create a class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Session3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Vehicle my_Car = new Vehicle;
        }
    }
    class Vehicle
    {
        uint mileage;
        byte year;
    }
}
```

I am getting the mentioned error on this line:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Vehicle my_Car = new Vehicle;
}
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: try this: Vehicle my_Car = new Vehicle();

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use

```
Vehicle my_Car = new Vehicle();
```

To call a constructor you need `()` after the class name, just like for function calls.

One of the following is required:

- `()` for a constructor call. e.g. `new Vehicle()` or `new Vehicle(...)`
- `{}` as an initializer, e.g. `new Vehicle { year = 2010, mileage = 10000}`
- `[]` for arrays, e.g. `new int[3]`, `new int[]{1, 2, 3}` or even just `new []{1, 2, 3}`

Answer (score 5):

The syntax should be:

```
Vehicle my_Car = new Vehicle();
```

Answer (score 3):

try `new Vehicle()`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are working with C# 3 or later, you can also use implicit typing and do this:

```
var my_Car = new Vehicle();
```

The same IL is produced in both cases.

Answer (score -1):

just making further clarification and adding a reference link, 
the syntax for allocating new memory space using the [new Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-operator) syntax is, 
creating objects

```
 Class1 obj  = new Class1();
```

creating instances of anonymous types

```
      var query = from cust in customers  
         select new { Name = cust.Name, Address = cust.PrimaryAddress };
```

invoke the default constructor for value types

```
int i = new int();
```

so in short and as the above answers already stated its a **missing brackets**  that is needed for dynamic allocation of memory for an object.