# .net 2.0 Causing Error: ' New type requires () ' - Only happens in .net 2.0

Tags: c#, console, codedom

The following code is being produced in CodeDom. When I set the target framework to .net 4.0 it works fine - no errors or warnings. When I set the target framework to .net 2.0, I get the following error:

> CS1526: A new expression requires () or [] after type

```
test soVar;
soVar = new test { foo = 0x10007 }; // Error occurs on this line

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct test
    {
        public uint foo;
    }
```

What is going on here?! Why would switching to .net 2.0 all of the sudden raise an error?

Look forward to any ideas here.

Thanks,

Evan

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909244/c-error-a-new-expression-requires-or-after-type

Comment: It's not a duplicate - I read that question already.

Comment: Can you be more specific?  When you say ".net 2.0" do you mean C# 2.0?  C# 3.0 runs on .net 2.0, and you're using a C# 3 feature.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
test soVar;
soVar = new test { foo = 0x10007 }; // Error occurs on this line
```

.net 2.0 does not support object initializers. it will have to do

```
test soVar;
soVar = new test(); 
soVar.foo = 0x10007;
```

Comment: .net 2.0 does support initializers, because C# 3 is built on .net 2.0.  This is a C#2 vs C#3 issue i believe.

Answer (score 0):

I am running Visual Studio 2010, and do not experience the problem you describe.

I created a project with **.Net Framework 2.0** as the target, and this program compiles:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct test
    {
        public uint foo;
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            test soVar;
            soVar = new test { foo = 0x10007 };
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe you are somehow using **C# 2.0** (e.g. Visual Studio 2005), not **.Net 2.0**?

To solve this problem, use Bala's solution (don't use object initializers).

Comment: I think you are on to something major here - can we chat somehow?